Winforms Livechart Cartesian Chart runs slow when opening in a new form
When try open a new form (separate window) with a cartesian chart it only updates every so often or not at all. I found something similar in this post:
https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/issues/599
but couldn't find an exact answer for my problem.
I have tried opening the form embedded in the main form and that works perfectly fine.
I originally had it placed in a tab control but even outside of it it wont work.
I'd appreciate any answers thanks!
